# Sequence of 8 numbers such that the sum of any of these numbers does not equal a number in the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Problem: Find a sequence of 8 numbers such that the sum of any of these numbers does not equal a number in the sequence.

For example, a sequence of prime numbers 2,3,5,7... would not satisfy because 2+3=5 and 2+5=7...

Thanks a Lot.

Comment: Edited as requested in such a way that it is a mathematical problem. Minor change. In any case you can close the question as it has been resolved. Thanks

Comment: any sequence of odd numbers would do

Comment: would not: 1,3,5,7,9... 1+3+5=9

Comment: from your examples I assumed you meant *sum of any two*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Make it an increasing sequence, and make sure that each number in the sequence is larger than the sum of all of the earlier numbers.

Comment: Thanks, got it. It comes down to a sequence starting at any number and multiplying successively by 2 to get the sequence. e.g.   (1,2,4,6,8,16,32,64,128)

Comment: @Walter: That's the most efficient one, yes. (You have an extra $6$ in there that you didn’t intend.) You’re welcome!